# Determine the flux of the field (x,y,z) through the surface z=$\sqrt(x^2+y^2-15)$, 16 ≤$x^2+y^2$≤40 with outward pointing unitnormal

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, divergence-theorem

Determine the flux of the field (x,y,z) through the surface z=$\sqrt(x^2+y^2-15)$   ,  16 ≤$x^2+y^2$≤40 with outward pointing unitnormal.

I understand that you need to use Gauss's divergence theorem, but I can't seem to workout the integrals. I bound the region with three surfaces, two circles at the top and bottom and then the surface z=$\sqrt(x^2+y^2-15)$.

I am having troubles working out the flux through the top and bottom surfaces. I am using the formula \begin{equation}
 \iint \limits_{}^{} u N dS
\end{equation}

For the bottom surface I get \begin{equation}
 \iint \limits_{}^{} (x,y,z)(0,0,-1) dxdy= \iint \ -z   dxdy
\end{equation}

I get stuck here. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes close the surface with disks at top (in plane $z = 5$) and bottom (in plane $z = 1$) and apply divergence theorem.

Divergence of the vector field $\nabla \cdot (x,y,z) = 3$.

Using cylindrical coordinates, the surface is

$z = \sqrt{r^2-15} \implies r^2 = z^2 + 15$.

We also know $16 \leq r^2 \leq 40$. That leads to $1 \leq z \leq 5$.

So total flux can be calculated as

$\displaystyle 3 \int_1^5 \pi(z^2+15) \ dz$.

Now we will find flux through the bottom disk.

$\vec F \cdot \hat{n} = (x,y,1) \cdot (0, 0, -1) = -1$

So the surface integral will be equal to the area of the disk with minus sign, which is $ - 16 \pi$.

Similarly for flux through the top surface,

$\vec F \cdot \hat{n} = (x,y,5) \cdot (0, 0, 1) = 5$

So the flux is $5$ times the area of the disk which is $200 \pi$.

Net outward flux through both top and bottom disks $ = 184 \pi$.

Now subtract that from the total flux through closed surface to get the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Why did you but z=1 and z=5 when calculating the flux through the top and bottom disk, if the field is (x, y, z)?

Comment: but we are in plane $z = 1$ and in plane $z = 5$. So the $z$ component of vector field will be $1$ and $5$ respectively.

Comment: When we say vector field is $(x, y, z)$, what does that mean? At any point on the surface, the vector field will be equal to $(x,y,z)$, which is the coordinate of the point. For the disks, only $x, y$ vary and $z$ is constant throughout the disk surface.

Comment: I understand, thank you! However, when I calculate the total flux I get 304$\pi$ and subtracting the flux from the top and bottom disk gives me a total flux of -80$\pi$  and the answer is 120$\pi$?

Comment: total flux through top and bottom disks is $184 \pi$, correct? So yes you should get an answer of $120 \pi$.

Comment: I see, sorry. I am not sure I understand how you got the integral for the total surface, I get \begin{equation}
 \int \limits_{}^{} \int \limits_{}^{} \int \limits_{}^{}3 dxdydz= 3\int \limits_{}^{} \int \limits_{}^{}( \int \limits_{1}^{5} dz) dxdy = 12 \int \limits_{0}^{2\pi} \int \limits_{4}^{\sqrt40}r dr d\theta=288\pi
\end{equation}. Why would you substitute the expression for $r^2$ into the integral?

Comment: That is not correct. What you are doing will give you volume of a cylinder of radius $\sqrt40$ of height $4$. with cylinder of radius 4 cut out of it, which is annulus.

Comment: if you are integrating wrt z first, then you will have to break your integral into two. For r between 0 and 4, yes z is between 1 and 5. But beyond r = 4, the lower bound of z is $\sqrt {r^2- 15}$. Pls draw a 2D sketch of the surface to see it. So itis easier to integrate wrt r first. Volume of any disk of thickness dz at height z is $\pi r^2 \ dz$ but r is a function of z: $ r = \sqrt{z^2 + 15}$. You can use this to set up triple integral if you like. Same thing.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it.